# Using Frida - How to get an instance of the function which gets invoked via AIDL interface

Tags: android, bind, aidl, frida

I am trying to call a function which is bind through AIDL interface
I have two packages

1. com.android.package1
2. com.android.package2

Inside package 2 I have class com.android.package2.example
which is invoked through intent from package 1.
The Iexample.aidl file has the following methods

```
interface Iexample {
    List<Object> getList();
    void onReceive(in Object result);
}
```

in package1 class

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName paramComponentName, IBinder paramIBinder) {
            mExample = Iexample.Stub.asInterface(paramIBinder);
            if(mExample != null) {
                mExample.onRecieve(mResult);
            }
        }
}
```

Now I am hooking package 2 via frida and want to directly invoke onReceive function so that I can pass result object that I have created. So please help me how do I write frida script?
[AIDL interface between two package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56sTG.png)

Comment: Hey, Your both packages have the same .aidl file right?

Comment: Yes, Iexample.aidl

Comment: If you have Iexample.aidl file in two package "com.android.package1" and "com.android.package2" aidl communication will not take place because the package names are different. Your Iexample.aidl file shoud be in the same package for both client and service. I hope this help.

Additionally this tutorial will also help if you are facing issue in aidl communication:
https://youtu.be/QTxX5X3XxHE

Comment: My AIDL files are under same package. the two application has different package. Also the communication is happening between these two application. Only thing is I want to call one of the function of this AIDL interface from my Frida script

Comment: You'd have to hook it higher up than onReceive. You'd have to look into the ServiceConnection class source code.